# Cannot start (or even init) Karma on a new machine

Tags: node.js, npm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

After installing node.js, npm, python, and karma... can't run it as I keep getting the following message:

```
karma init
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './modules/core.log'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\JsVortex\node_modules\core-js\index.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\JsVortex\node_modules\karma\lib\file-list.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
```

When I check:

```
C:\Projects\JsVortex\node_modules\core-js\index.js
```

Line 15 contains the following line: `require('./modules/core.log');`

Any ideas how to fix it? 
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you create a `core.log` file in that folder?

Comment: It worked!!! :) Thanks a lot!